# Black screen when I make a table View

Tags: uikit, tableview

I implemented a simple code to have a custom TableView but the result is a black screen on the simulator.

What kind of problem do you think here?
How can I explain it more clear?

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let animals = ["Lion", "Elephant", "Monkey", "Panda"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {   
        return animals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: (animals[indexPath.row] + ".jpg"))
        cell.myLabel.text = animals[indexPath.row]
        return (cell)
    } 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you set the controller as the tableView's delegate and dataSource?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your ViewController the tableView's delegate and dataSource.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you declare your `tableview` anywhere.
The view controller was subclassed from `UIViewController`, not `UITableViewController`- correct?

Create and instantiate a `tableview`, something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController //...
    var tableview: UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableview = UITableView()
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.datasource = self
```